# Can't get rid of sda5 partition

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, encryption

The other day I tried installing Ubuntu using the HDD encryption option. Something went wrong in the process and the installation failed, so I tried again, this time without encrypting. I discovered that the sda5 partition that's created in the encryption process was still there, and was resulting in an error message during the boot process.

I've since tried erasing and reformatting the drive at least five times (it's an SSD), but no matter what I do, that sda5 partition always shows up and causes that same error message.

I've tried ATA secure erase, I've tried zeroing out the drive using `dd`, I've tried reformatting the drive using the disk utility and selecting "no partitions," but every attempt has failed. I re-install the OS on the drive and that same error message comes up, and when I look, there's the sda5 "unknown" partition. Any ideas as to how I can get rid of it?

Comment: What did you click on in Disks to reformat the drive? In the top right there's the little cog menu, did you select it from there? I'm pretty sure you need to erase the Master Boot Record (MBR) so that Ubuntu will write a new one when you install (although it should have done this anyway).

Comment: Could you boot from a LiveDVD, go straight to `gparted` and post a screen shot of that drive?